# IBM Websphere Portal Page Caching

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I am using websphere portal server 7. I want to disable caching of a portlet, how can i do this ? Can any one guide me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to disable portlet caching in IBM Websphere portal 7. It is the feature of IBM portal server. However, we can use portlet events to override cached data.

(Note : I finally reached to this solution after getting PMR response from IBM).

Comment: There are some point I may have misunderstood, but a Portlet (old IBM API and JSR 168) can define its own cache time within the code. As documented here. 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+7+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Caching_portlet_output_wp7&content=pdcontent